# Convert SQL query to LINQ with a group by

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the below sql query that i am able to conert into LINQ

```
select count(*), BatchID 
from TimeSheetHeader 
group by BatchID having count(*) > 1
```

converts to

```
var duplicateBatchIDList = from c in _db.TimeSheetHeaders
                                               group c by c.BatchID into grp
                                               where grp.Count() > 1
                                               select grp;
```

But now i am trying to throw an extra column that isnt included in the group by. I have the SQL query

```
select count(*), BatchID, TimeSheetCreationDate = min( TimeSheetCreationDate     ) 
from TimeSheetHeader 
where TimeSheetCreationDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
group by BatchID having count(*) > 1
```

But i am not sure how this convert over to LINQ

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from c in _db.TimeSheetHeaders
where c.TimeSheetCreationDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
group c by c.BatchID into grp
where grp.Count() > 1
select new
{
    BatchID = grp.Key,
    Count = grp.Count(),
    TimeSheetCreationDate = grp.Min(x => x.TimeSheetCreationDate)
}
```

Comment: where came `g` on `g.key` ?

Comment: yes g doesnt exist here, neither does c within the new

Comment: also i added DateTime.Now to replace Current_Timestamp

Comment: Updated the query to filter on `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and the typo with `g`

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the lambda expression version of the query:

```
var result = TimeSheetHeader
    .Where(t => t.TimeSheetCreationDate >= TIMESTAMP)
    .GroupBy(t => t.BatchID)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => new 
        {
            Count = g.Count(),
            BatchID = g.Key,
            TimeSheetCreationDate = g.Min(x => x.TimeSheetCreationDate)
        })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

I slightly modified Magnus's answer

```
var duplicateBatchIDList = (from c in _db.TimeSheetHeaders
                                               group c by c.BatchID into grp
                                               where grp.Count() > 1
                                               select new
                                               {
                                                   BatchID = grp.FirstOrDefault().BatchID,                                                      
                                                   TimeSheetCreationDate = grp.Min(x => x.TimeSheetCreationDate)
                                               }).Where(x => x.TimeSheetCreationDate <= DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: how can this be downvoted when it works? The other answers have "Key" which doesnt get recognized because it isnt a key.

Comment: `IGrouping` which `grp` is has `Key`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Monzingo please check my answer